# Chrome app - error when call channel.open() using GAE channel javascript API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine, google-chrome-app, channel

My server is running on google app engine, my client is a chrome app using angular framework. I'm trying to implement Channel Java API service of GAE.
My problem is when channel.open() was called angular show this error at the console: 'beforeunload is not available in packaged apps.' Below is my code, written in controller:

```
var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
console.log("channel");
var socket = channel.open();
console.log("socket");
socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log(open);
};

console.log("on open");
socket.onmessage = function(msg){
    console.log("Message: "+msg);
}
```

(Console show "channel" but not "socket")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an AngularJS service to hold the list of the chats. This is
  not required but it is the recommended way to share an observable
  array (which means with two-way data binding) between controllers.
- Initiate  the Channel API inside that service. Now there's the trick : for the modifications to the observable array to be pushed to the controllers, we need to use the $rootScope method.

Ref -   [app-engine-channel-api-and-angularjs](http://david-codes.blogspot.in/2013/03/app-engine-channel-api-and-angular-js.html)

Comment: I commented the line 'beforeunload' in channel.js. My project is running now, hope there's no big problem in the future. Thanks for the reference anyway